# Inserting empty datarows into a Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a gridview where User can insert rows. I am trying to have 10 empty rows in the grid with all the columns empty. Is it possible?

User just need to enter into textboxes, so i will have to save all the 10 rows into the database! This is using c# asp.net..

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="50">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtSpots" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Spots")%>' Width="45px">           </asp:TextBox>                           
      </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="180">
      <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompanyName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CompanyName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
         </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Spots");
dt.Columns.Add("CompanyName");

int i = 0;
while(i<10)
{
   DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
   dr["Spots"] = "";
   dr["CompanyName"] = "";

   dt.Rows.Add(dr);
   i++;
}

MyGrid.DataSource = dt;
MyGrid.DataBound();
```